# Unity 3D Door Script Angle Transformation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i write the following code for open and close doors:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LittleDoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool doorOpen = false;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private float distance = 5.0f;
    public GameObject door;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance))
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == door.name)
                {
                    if (!doorOpen)
                    {
                        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f);
                        hit.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, 2.0f);
                        doorOpen = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Quaternion targetRotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                        hit.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation2, 2.0f);
                        doorOpen = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is the door not open in the right angle and if i close the door the not go back in the start position.
Maybe somebosy have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the angle to -90, it always happens to me.

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f);
```

the second one:

```
Quaternion targetRotation2 = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: it have not the right effect. my door have the following start data:            Position X -0.038414 Y -1.699535 Z 12.69733                                Rotation X 270 Y 180 Z 0                                                                      Scale X 110.0246 Y 17.51499 Z 6.972782

Comment: now the door transform to a other position and back to a other one, but not to the origin position

Comment: You could try to create a variable at Start method that  gets the original position of the door, so the targetRotation2 will be equal to this variable. To know the value of the first rotation, make it manually in the editor and see in the inspector the value of rotation that looks good then put it on code... hope it works *-*